# default sms app doesn't open on KITKAT nexus 5

Tags: android, google-hangouts

OK, i've tried everything (including several hours of reading and trying a lot of stuff on stackoverflow)

I'm trying to launch the default sms app from the android launcher, and using this code:

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(smsIntent);
        break;
```

It works great on all phones BUT my NEXUS 5 .

Guess it has something to do with KITKAT, but not sure how to fix it..

Important - Im not trying to send the text or get it from the user (as i've seen people do here), just getting the user to the main screen of the sms app (hangouts in my case).

Thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

ComponentName cm =new ComponentName("com.google.android.talk","com.google.android.talk.SigningInActivity");

intent.setComponent(cm);
```

this adapter nexus, I get the ComponentName by ADB log.